# I have been using this statement in windows command prompt for importing .dmp files . what does the word 'full' mean here?

Tags: database, oracle, import, command-prompt, dmp

I have been using this statement in windows command prompt for importing .dmp files . what does the word 'full' mean here ?

```
imp me_user/password_me file='C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.dmp' full=Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle Database there many schemas for example hr, scott,system and sys etc.

> If I am importing single user then i will use imp hr/hr
>   file='C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.dmp'
>   log=file='C:\Users\user\Desktop\hr-imp.lo

g

so the above statement will import only hr user.

If I use full=y

> imp system/manager file='C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.dmp'
>   log=file='C:\Users\user\Desktop\full-imp.log full=y

Now all the four users(hr, scott,system and sys) will be imported automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To import the entire contents of the dump file, use the FULL=Y parameter as follows:

imp userid=system/manager file=my_dump.dmp full=y log=imp.log

Please go through the below link:-

> [Use FULL=Y to get entire contents of the DUMP file](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Importing-dmp-file-via-command-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

the user(`me_user`) and the tablespaces will be automatically created with `full` option set to `Y` at the new place where your datas imported to.